# Order of evaluation when testing equivalence of booleans

Tags: python, boolean, operator-precedence

I just encountered the following and am curious about Python's behavior:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> x in range(2)
True
>>> type(x in range(2))
<type 'bool'>
>>> x in range(2) == True
False
>>> x in range(2) == False
False
>>> (x in range(2)) == True
True
```

In particular, why does `(1 in range(2)) == True` evaluate `True` and `l in range(2) == True` evaluate to `False`? It seems like there is some strange order of evaluation behavior in the latter, except that if you make the order explicitly wrong, you get a `TypeError`:

```
>>> x in (range(2) == True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

For the record, I don't know any cases where I would use `x in range(2) == True` instead of just `x in range (2)`, but would just like to know why this is happening. I also tested this in both Python2.7 and Python3, and the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below expression:

```
x in range(2) == True
```

is chained comparison, and is evaluated as:

```
x in range(2) and range(2) == True
```

which will give you `False` as `range(2) == True` is evaluated to `False`. See documentation for [Comparison](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).

Comment: Good insight! For some reason I never thought you could chain `in` with other operators.

Answer (score 3):

The `==` equality and `in` membership operators are both [comparison operators](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in), and these can be *chained*.

Chaining takes the form of `expr1 op1 expr2 op2 expr3`, which is interpreted as `(expr1 op1 expr2) and (expr2 op2 expr3)` but the middle `expr2` is only evaluated once.

So, your examples are really:

```
x in range(2) and range(2) == True
```

and `range(2)` is never equal to a boolean value.

Note that you should really never compare to `== True` or `== False`. Leave that to `while` or `if` to test *for* you.

Answer (score -1):

I think is becuause you are actually just evaluating the `range(2)` part which if you try it in the interpreter you get this.

```
>>> range(2) == True
>>> False
```